# Smooth animation in Swing

Tags: java, swing, animation, repaint

How do I animate a JPanel at the maximum refresh rate of the client's monitor?

What I would like to happen is that `paintComponent` is only called after the last update. I could do this by using a `Timer` to schedule `repaint()` every (1000 / 60) ms, but I'm just guessing at what the refresh rate is.

Effectively I'd like `repaint` to be called continuously. But if I call `repaint` 200 times per second and the EDT isn't busy, it executes `paintComponent` 200 times per second, which is inefficient use of processor time and could aversely impact the rest of the application's performance.

Comment: This may be off topic, but the [`RepaintManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RepaintManager.html) collapses multiple requests into a single repaint for members of a component tree.

Comment: are you sure that you really want to repaint() a lot of times? Will you have that much change in the objects inside the JPanel? Or you're thinking about animating it like moving a image inside it, like a game?

Comment: Are you unable to tell when you actually need to do a repaint?

Comment: @woliveirajr yes, I'm thinking of a game. @little I don't have that book. @Perception it's possible but unlikely that no repaint is necessary; however I don't want to schedule unnecessary repaints

Comment: @Luigi : I'm a bit busy right now, so I can't do research to help you. But try finding more about sprites, animation, or even java games. I'm almost sure that placing new objects (or changing their attributes) and repainting will be the correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure repainting at the monitor's refresh rate is a good idea. But if you are looking to find out what the refresh rate is you can use this piece of code (shamelessly copied from the interwebs).

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment
        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();

for (int i = 0; i < gs.length; i++) {
    DisplayMode dm = gs[i].getDisplayMode();

    // Get refresh rate in Hz
    int refreshRate = dm.getRefreshRate();
    if (refreshRate == DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN) {
        // Unknown rate
    } else {
        System.out.println(refreshRate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe what I actually want to do is to recalculate position of the animation at the refresh rate, rather than the repaint itself, and trigger a repaint from that if necessary.

Comment: I think that will work well. If the number of sprites is very complicated then you can refresh at whatever fps is most appropriate. I would recommend double buffering to smooth the animation as much as possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all Swing is double-buffered by default these days

Comment: @Luigi - you're right, its on by default. http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/#db. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm agreed with `@little bunny foo foo` and you have to calculate with OS Latency too, this value depends of HW & SW, then my WinXp has value around 63ms, by overlocking this frequency you get Error from RepaintManager, for example JTable is very sensitive JComponents, please read more about painting in Swing [paintImmediately()](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/), repaint() create EDT by defalut

EDIT: to blow away all possible doubts about repaint(); look here [painting and javax.swing.Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678065/why-doesnt-my-repaint-work/6678312#6678312)